# Error while creating Worker in Twilio TaskRouter

Tags: nodes, twilio

I am working on contact center using Twilio in Node js for that I am using TaskRouter but getting error in below code.

```
 var capability = new twilio.TaskRouterWorkerCapability(accountSid,authToken, workspaceSid, workerSid);
    capability.allowActivityUpdates();
    capability.allowReservationUpdates();
    token = capability.generate();
    agent = new twilio.TaskRouter.Worker(token); // Here getting below error.

TypeError: Cannot read property 'Worker' of undefined
```

Is I am missing something? and how can I update the activity of the particular worker. I did the below code changes but it is not updating the status or activity of Worker.

```
client.workspace.workers(workerSid).update({
        /*attributes: '{"type":"support"}',*/
        ActivitySid:'WAa8affefa7a655a86201f05317bfd2ba4' // idle
    }, function(err, worker) {
        console.log(worker.sid);
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio employee here.

Are you trying to update a Worker's activity from a client or on the node server?

The former is key for agents to update their state (this is the most common). Although if you want to force an agent into a particular state that TaskRouter doesn't automatically do, then you can do so server-side.

**Updating Worker Activity from a JS Client**

Everything looks good from the JWT generation perspective, however you need to return the token to the JS client-side to initiate the Worker JS.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//media.twiliocdn.com/taskrouter/js/v1.2/taskrouter.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var workerToken = generateWorkerToken(); // calls your node server to generate the JWT
    var worker = new Twilio.TaskRouter.Worker(workerToken);
    worker.update({"ActivitySid":"WAa8affefa7a655a86201f05317bfd2ba4"},
        function(err, worker) {
            console.log(worker.sid);
        });
</script>
```

For more information on TaskRouter Worker.js, you can check this out here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/taskrouter/worker-js

**Updating Worker Activity from a Node Server**

If you're looking to update a Worker's Activity from a node server, there's no need to generate a JWT since this is for client side authentication.

You can simply utilize the function you're already doing:

```
var client = new twilio.TaskRouterClient('AC123', '123', 'WS123');
client.workspace.workers(workerSid).update({
    /*attributes: '{"type":"support"}',*/
    ActivitySid:'WAa8affefa7a655a86201f05317bfd2ba4' // idle
}, function(err, worker) {
    console.log(worker.sid);
})
```

The key is that *twilio* indicates node-server side use where as *Twilio.TaskRouter.Worker* indicates client-side use.

Comment: Why aren't the docs for `twilio.TaskRouterClient('AC123', '123', 'WS123');` available anywhere on Twilio?